# AWK function of twisting a graph shape

Tags: awk

I am facing a problem to create a function to twist a shape of a graph. the equation of the graph is given by `y=ax^2+bx`. I would like to twist a graph in blue colour into red colour.

[image: graph]

I understand that to twist the graph, it should increase a and b, while loop is also needed to complete the function. Below is the coding that not completed. Can anyone help me?

```
while()
{
    a++
    b++
    total=0
    for(i=1; i<=count; i++)
    {
        newy[I] = a*x[I]*x[I] + b*x[I]
    }
```

This is what I can think of. What element should I include in my coding again?

Comment: if you don't have the equation parameters and doing this visually, I don't think 100% accuracy is possible.  Red parabola equation looks like y=2x(x+2)=2x^2+4x.   For blue relative to red, decrease the ratio of b/a in absolute value.

Comment: This is **much** more of a graph theory question than an awk question. Once you have the algorithm we can help you implement it in awk but it doesn't make sense to ask for help coming up with th algorithm in a question tagged just with awk. You MIGHT get lucky but....

Comment: if the equation given is y=2x^2+5x for the blue graph and y=3x^2+6x for the red graph. So what should I do first?

Comment: admittedly I don't know much, but how are you thinking that this question is an awk question? i think you could get more assistance if people knew what you were really asking.